# How can I make sure that build steps are auto-detected by TeamCity 8.1?

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity 8.1's build steps configuration page has a tantalising looking button:

[image: TeamCity Build Steps configuration]

Sadly, I am not worthy:

[image]

I can't find much documentation on what actually needs to be in the repository to have the step autodetected. There's a brief mention in the ["What's new" for TeamCity 8.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+8.1):

> TeamCity auto-detection mechanism supports most popular version
>   control systems and a wide range of build tools and technologies,
>   including: Maven, Gradle, Ant, NAnt, MSBuild, Visual Studio solution,
>   Powershell, Xcode, Rake, IntelliJ IDEA, as well as various command
>   line scripts.

and it's mentioned in the [general manual](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Build+Steps):

> Build steps are configured on the Build Steps section of the Build
>   Configuration Settings page: the steps can be auto-detected by
>   TeamCity or added manually.

but none of this tells me how it decides whether a particular MSBuild project/PowerShell script etc should be selected.

What does TeamCity look for when auto-detecting build steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When auto-detecting build steps, TeamCity peeks into version control system. For this process to take reasonable time, TeamCity only looks 2 levels deep into the source code tree. Moreover, if some suitable files were found on the first level, it does not go to second.

As for criteria for the build steps to be discovered:

- For PowerShell build step, TeamCity looks for files with `.ps1` extension
- For MSBuild build step, TeamCity looks for files with `.targets`, `.proj` and `.build` extensions
- For VisualStudio solution step, TeamCity looks for files with `.sln` extension

Please note, that if any files discovered were already configured by hand in some previous steps, they will not be discovered again

Comment: Thanks! Are any files with those extensions suitable, or are there any further conditions based on contents or naming?

Comment: For now we look only on file extensions to avoid traffic while looking inside files.